# How to add a ListBox programmatically in a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I started out `C#` very recently and sorry if this question sounds dumb.

How do I add a Listbox in a Form that pops out from a Button click?

Note: The Form isn't the one that's added from the Solution Explorer whereby I can just drag a Listbox from the Toolbox to my Form.

So what I want is to create a ListBox in my file `drawer1Form` where I can add additional items. Thanks for the help in advance!:)

```
private void drawer1button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        // Drawer 1 Button
    {
        drawer1Form df1 = new drawer1Form();
        df1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        df1.Show();
    }
    public partial class drawer1Form : Form                         // Creates drawer1Form
    {
        public drawer1Form()
        {
           Text = "Drawer 1 ";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding the designer?  It would teach you a lot about how a form creates its controls and wires up its events.

Comment: @LarsTech by designer you meant the Form that i can add via the solution explorer? (sorry not used to C#, still learning.) Not avoiding because my original program was to have Form2 popup if i pressed a button in Form1. And a ListBox in another Form when i clicked a button in Form2, so i don't think i need a fully customizable Form added via the Designer. Just a simple coded one with a ListBox will do haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same way as you'd do with any other object.

In the class of your form add a

```
private ListBox myAwesomeListBox;
```

Then in the button event handler add something like this:

```
myAwesomeListBox = new ListBox();
myAwesomeListBox.SuspendLayout();

// set all the properties that you want
myAwesomeListBox.Name = "myAwesomeListBox";
myAwesomeListBox.Location = new Point(...); // place it somewhere
myAwesomeListBox.Size = new Size(...); // give it a size
// etc...

df1.Controls.Add(myAwesomeListBox);
myAwesomeListBox.ResumeLayout();
```

This should be it.

I highly advise you to do it through the designer first though, and then take a look at the generated code in the form's `.Designer.cs` file, you'll have a very good understanding after reading through that.